# Word order with 'used to'

Tags: word-order

Is there a difference between

> I didn't use to do that

and

> I used to not to do that

For example,

> I don't use to read books when I was a child.

Would both be correct? Is the second even correct grammatically?

Comment: The idiom _used to_, always pronounced /'yustə/, can either be a verb in the past tense, followed by an infinitive, and presupposing that the present tense is false (_I used to live on DeKalb Avenue_); or preceded by a form of _be_, it means 'accustomed to; adapted to', as in _I'm used to living on DeKalb Avenue now_.

Comment: I didn't used to read books, but now I do.

Comment: "I used to do a lot of drugs.  I still do, but I used to, too." - Mitch Hedberg (re presupposition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Michael Swan's "Practical English Usage", the negative forms of *used to* are:

> **formal:** used not to
>
> **informal:** didn't use to, didn't used to

Example:

> I didn't use(d) to read books when I was a child. (informal)
>
> I used not to read books when I was a child. (formal)

So, the difference would be mostly that of register.

Comment: I've never heard a native English speaker says _I used not to do that_ or _I used not to read books_. How would it be pronounced, for starts? /ayustnat/ or /ayuzdnat/? Does Swan cover the pronunciation? If not, it's useless pedantry.

Answer (score 0):

The first example suggests your habit, whereas your second example is not grammatically correct. Instead it should be "I used to not do that".